# Discord.py Bot make op.gg

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

So im trying to make a bot where when i type !opgg it will then ask "Please Give me 5 summoner names :)" and then when someone would type 5 names it would split them up and add them onto the end of https://oce.op.gg/multi/query= adding ", " at the end, i want it so i would have to type a name then send then it would ask for another name.

**This is the code i have so far**

```
import discord
import config

from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=config.PREFIX)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("-----")
    print("Bot is online!")
    print("-----")

@bot.command()
async def opgg(ctx):
    await ctx.send("Please Give me 5 summoner names :)")


    

bot.run(config.TOKEN)
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code-writing or tutorial service. Please [edit] your question and post [what you have tried so far](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592), including example input, expected output, the actual output (if any), and the [**full text** of any errors or tracebacks](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359146), *all as formatted text in the question itself.* Do not post images of text.

Comment: What is your question? If you would like to learn how to use discord.py with op.gg's api then you should check https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/". There doesn't seem to be a op.gg api but https://github.com/stephenpoole/op.gg-api for nodejs. You could also use https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/ to scrape op.gg but that might be against their policy (so check first).

Answer (score 0):

Like `@MattDMo` said, you should provide what you have tried so far and rewrite your question. You can try something like this

```py
@bot.command()
async def opgg(ctx,*summonerNames):
    names = ', '.join(summonerNames)
    url = f'https://oce.op.gg/multi/query={names}'
    return await ctx.send(url)
```

Now you can do `!opgg "Hide on Bush" "PawN" "Uzi" "Trick2g"`
You will need to use quotations for this to work if you want users to be able to use space in names.

**2021 World Champions without Space**

`!opgg Meiko Viper Scout Jiejie Flandre`

Please consider learning how to use the Riot Games API for [League of Legends](https://developer.riotgames.com/apis)  yourself as scraping op.gg is not as reliable. You can also use other libs like [Riot-Watcher](https://github.com/pseudonym117/Riot-Watcher) or [cassiopeia](https://github.com/meraki-analytics/cassiopeia)